# Adding an early return to avoid using else and additional nesting

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, cypress

I got the below comment from a developer:
" add an early return here to avoid using else and additional nesting". But I have a bit of difficulty with modifying.

Can you please let me know what exactly should I do in this case?
Thank you!

```
failOnStatusCode: false,

    }).then((res) => {


      // Assertion for one by one

      if (res.status != 200) {

        cy.log(JSON.stringify(res));

      } else {

        expect(res.body.id).to.eq(vehicleIdBuyNow);

        expect(res.body.auctionStatus).contains("finished");

        expect(res.body.price).to.be.equal(minPrice);

        expect(res.body.winningBidPlatformId).contains(platformIdBuyNow);

        expect(true).to.be.true;
```

Answer (score 4):

The recommendation is to change it to:

```
.then((res) => {
    if (res.status != 200) {
        cy.log(JSON.stringify(res));
        return; // exit function, no need for an `else` after this
    }
    expect(res.body.id).to.eq(vehicleIdBuyNow);
    expect(res.body.auctionStatus).contains("finished");
    expect(res.body.price).to.be.equal(minPrice);
    expect(res.body.winningBidPlatformId).contains(platformIdBuyNow);
    expect(true).to.be.true;
```

Comment: if (res.status != 200) return cy.log(JSON.stringify(res));

Comment: I would though instead of JSON.stringify, if possible do the conversion yourself it's less expensive on CPU (if this is server-sided).

Comment: I'd only do that if the next `.then` is expected to use that return value, which is quite unlikely - otherwise, the intent of the code is clearer if nothing is returned.

Comment: Perfect, all is covered! :)